# SQL ODBC Sybase TO_DATE Procedure not provided

Tags: sql, odbc, sybase

I have a task to finish in SQL, and am not very familiar with the language. The normal resource I would use is sick currently, so I'm asking for help here instead. I'm running the following query on Sybase:

```
SELECT WgArt, SrtNr, Datum, WNetto 
FROM M01.Wgs 
WHERE (WgArt <> 'f') AND (SrtNr = '170904-01') AND 
      (Datum BETWEEN to_date('09.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy') AND 
                     to_date('09.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy')
      ) OR
      (SrtNr = '170904-02') OR
      (SrtNr = '170904-05') OR
      (SrtNr = '170904-07') OR
      (SrtNr = '150106-03')
```

The error message I'm receiving is: "Procedure 'to_date' is not found".
[Error msg 42S02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No5TU.png)

I googled and found some workaround articles with [CAST/Convert](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/4/157858.aspx), but also getting same error. Any idea would be welcome.

Comment: Use parentheses around the clauses in the `where`, so the logic is what you intend.

Comment: can you confirm that you're using Sybase (now SAP) SQLAnywhere? (the error message link suggests you're using SQLAnywhere, but there are 4x different Sybase RDBMS products so we need to know exactly which RDBMS product you're using)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `IN` clause rather that strange `OR` clause :

```
SELECT WgArt, SrtNr, Datum, WNetto 
FROM M01.Wgs 
WHERE (WgArt <> 'f') AND 
      (Datum BETWEEN to_date('09.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy') AND 
                     to_date('09.02.2017','dd.mm.yyyy')
      ) AND (SrtNr IN ('170904-01', '170904-02', '170904-05', '170904-07', '150106-03')
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your product is Sybase (now SAP) SQLAnywhere, there is no `to_date()` function.

Here's a [list of date-related functions supported by SQLAnywhere](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/fudt.html).

Of specific interest might be the `date()`, `datetime()` and/or `dateformat()` functions ... ?